# Attribute type date displaying wrong format

Tags: attributes

I create a date attribute with date type as date. In the admin the date format is MM/DD/YYYY but when the date appears on the front-end of the product page the date format is DD/MM/YYYY

Any insight on how to get the front-end to match the admin would be great. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The way dates are formatted depends on the `locale` set in the shop. To change your `locale` you can check `BE > System > Configuration > General > Locale tab` and change the value of the `Locale` dropdown.

Optionally you can also configure date formatting for the catalog section in your shops from `BE > System > Configuration > Catalog > Date & Time Custom Options`.

[image]